# How does returning a value work in a recursive method? [Java]

Tags: java, recursion, switch-statement, return-value, boolean-expression

**TLDR :** *java seems to only return the first value when the method is run. Am I wrong about this, or is there a workaround I'm not aware of [without resorting to loops]* ?

My goal is to output the last value [boolean] from the return which gets assigned to the method, however I am unable to do it without a proper understanding of how return works.

---

Aim of the code is to return a boolean, from a simple choice [Y/N] by reading user input. If a wrong output [eg: "p","P","apples"] is given, the method should prompt the user again, until the right input is given.

This is what I started out with:

```
private Boolean nrCheck()
{   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    Boolean isNewRelease;


    System.out.println("New Release [Y/N]? ");      
    String movieType = sc.nextLine();       

    switch (movieType)
    {
        case "Y" : case "y" :              isNewRelease = true;  break;
        case "N" : case "n" :              isNewRelease = false; break;
        default  : /*Try again*/ nrCheck();                      break; 
    }

    return isNewRelease;
}
```

Obviously this won't work, since the default case does not assign a value,
resulting in an **Initialization error.**

Attempted to fix this by assigning a default value, like this :

```
private Boolean nrCheck()
{   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    Boolean isNewRelease;


    System.out.println("New Release [Y/N]? ");      
    String movieType = sc.nextLine();       

    switch (movieType)
    {
        case "Y" : case "y" :        isNewRelease = true;            break;
        case "N" : case "n" :        isNewRelease = false;           break;
        default  : /*printTryagain*/ isNewRelease = null;  nrCheck();break; 
    }

    return isNewRelease;
}
```

This presents a new problem. For some reason, when I recall the method again, the return value is already set. I've tried to play around with the order of the code, and it doesn't really do much. My speculation is that once you recall the method, the return value is automatically set, and you cannot change it if set the first time.

And I am aware I could do this,

```
private Boolean nrCheck()
{   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    Boolean isNewRelease;


    System.out.println("New Release [Y/N]? ");      
    String movieType = sc.nextLine();       

    do 
    {
        switch (movieType)
        {
            case "Y" : case "y" :        isNewRelease = true;            break;
            case "N" : case "n" :        isNewRelease = false;           break;
            default  : /*printTryagain*/ isNewRelease = null;  nrCheck();break; 
        }
    }
    while (movieType.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || movieType.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))

    return isNewRelease;
}
```

But personally prefer not to unless I'm fully aware there isn't another solution, or there isn't a blatantly obvious error in my code. [Also want to extend this code to become a bit more general-purpose].

Ultimately, I want to be able to understand what mistake I have made, or if there isn't any, the limitations of return in this case, even if it means I have to scrap my code for a do-while loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return the value returned by the recursive call:

```
private boolean nrCheck()
{   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("New Release [Y/N]? ");      
    String movieType = sc.nextLine();       

    switch (movieType)
    {
        case "Y" : case "y" : return true;
        case "N" : case "n" : return false;
        default  : return nrCheck();
    }
}
```

If you ignore that value, there's no point in making the recursive call in the first place.

P.S., you can probably change the return type of the method to `boolean`, since it can never return `null`.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! However I'm a bit confused since a boolean isn't actually returned from nrCheck? Does Java understand that there is intention to return a boolean value eventually, and overrides the initialization error until the conditions are met and a boolean is returned?

Comment: @rubyduby I'm not sure I'm following your question. The switch statement in my answer contains a return statement in all possible execution branches. Hence, the method is guaranteed to return a boolean.

Comment: Since values returned have to be  boolean, why is it that nrCheck is a valid return value, considering it isn't boolean? Is there an exception if you return the same method?

Comment: `nrCheck() ` returns a `Boolean` (or boolean, if you'll change he method's return type to `boolean`), so `return nrCheck(); returns a `Boolean`. @rubyduby

Comment: @rubyduby I changed the return type of the method to `boolean`, in case that's what was causing the confusion. However, Java can auto-box booleans to Booleans and auto-unbox Booleans to booleans when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you even need recursion here, and it looks like you are understanding what it is used for incorrectly.  Your third attempt with a `do` loop is the typical way you would poll a user for input:

```
private boolean nrCheck() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean isNewRelease;

    System.out.println("New Release [Y/N]? ");      
    menuRedirect(movieType);    // don't know what this is doing...

    do {
        String movieType = sc.nextLine();
    } while (!movieType.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !movieType.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));

    // at this point, the movie type can only be y/Y/n/N
    isNewRelease = movieType.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") ? true : false;

    return isNewRelease;
}
```

Comment: "MenuRedirect" just returns to the menu if you input nothing. However this is irrelevant to my question, so I'll remove it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I should however mention my misunderstanding was the reason I've asked the question in the first place [And I've attempted to point that out in multiple points in my question]; this answer hasn't addressed the issue as to where my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @rubyduby I don't think you should be using recursion here, and I've answered to this effect.  If you have some other problem where using recursion makes sense, then edit your question.

Comment: Biegelesien Perhaps this solution may be better without recursion, but ultimately that's not what my question was about. I have restated that in the last two lines for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**Just Make Small Change In Your Method As Given Below**

```
private Boolean nrCheck() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean isNewRelease = null;


    //While loop here which break only if isNewRelease value is 
    //Non null(true or false)
    while (isNewRelease == null) {

        System.out.println("New Release [Y/N]? ");
        String movieType = sc.nextLine();

        menuRedirect(movieType);

        switch (movieType) {
            case "Y":
            case "y":
                isNewRelease = true;
                break;
            case "N":
            case "n":
                isNewRelease = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Try Again");
                /*I removed recursive call which not required because recursive calls always creates new stack frames so it is recommenced that if we are going to use such calls we need to go with tail recursion.*/    
                isNewRelease = null;
                break;
        }

    }

    return isNewRelease;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what is the changes you have made, this is unclear. And give the reason.

Comment: Okay. I will its just a simple.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However this seems similar to the 2nd code block in my question, with the main difference being that you have instantiated isNewRelease in the beginning too. I have tried this, and it hasn't worked, returning the value null.  The only reason I choice not to mention this is because it would my question would be unnecessarily big.

Comment: Ah, I see what you have done now. Sorry for not noticing this earlier :)